# What is the difference between '..at 20 percent' and '..with 20 percent'

Tags: meaning

Consider the following two sentences:

America has the highest oil consumption rate **at**...% of the world total.

The Middle East has the largest oil reserves **with**...% of the world total.

What is the difference between using *at* and *with* in those examples.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question makes no sense. Could you try to expand a bit on it, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing here with what economists call, in the first example **a flow**, and in the second example **a stock**. A flow deals with an amount per period of time, either of production or usage, or expenditure or something. A stock deals with a holding, an inventory, or in this case an amount in reserve.

So in the first example it makes more sense to use *at*. America has the highest usage at X%.

The second example is talking about the amount of reserves held, so it seems more appropriate to say: ...the highest reserves with X%.

You will probably understand this better as you gain more experience of English prepositions. But for the time being I wouldn't be too concerned, because even if you interchanged the **at** and the **with** people would still understand perfectly what you meant.